# Discord JS category and returning ID

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to check (and create, if it does not exist) the checking process works fine.

Here is a copy of my code:

```
                var bb_admin='0';
                
                //Check if admin_logs exists if not create it
                if(message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "admin_logs") === undefined && typeof message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "admin_logs") == 'undefined')
                {
                    console.log("creating");
                    bb_admin = message.guild.channels.create('admin_logs', {parent: bb_cat});
                } else {
                    console.log("already exists");
                    bb_admin = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "admin_logs");}
                
                console.log('bb_admin after',bb_admin);
```

The problem which I'm having is I need to be able to assign the channel ID to a variable once it is created before moving on.

I cannot use a .then statement as the next steps has to happen outside of this. (I'm cycling a log file and populating the row into a channel based on contents).

What appears to be happening is I'm getting a promise back, however when I change this line:
bb_admin = message.guild.channels.create('admin_logs', {parent: bb_cat})
to:
bb_admin = await message.guild.channels.create('admin_logs', {parent: bb_cat})

to wait for the response I'm given the following error message: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61197547/get-id-after-discord-js-channel-creation) question which seems pretty much the same as what I'm trying to achieve. but even running attempt 2 presented with the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Any pointers where I am going wrong here, I've been going around in circles for a few days now.

Edit: Very Basic Example:

```
/**
 * @file app.js
 * @description BeerBot
 * @author Beer
 * @version 0.0.1
 */

// Require all needed packages and files
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client();


// Ready event
client.on('ready', () => {
    // Log when bot is ready
    console.log(`${client.user.tag} is online!`);
});

// Message event
client.on('message', message => {

    if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith("!")) return;
    
    //Try a simple category created command
    var bb_cat = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "BeerBot");
    var bb_admin = 0;
    
    //Check if admin_logs exists if not create it
    if(message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "admin_logs") === undefined && typeof message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "admin_logs") == 'undefined')
    {
        //Try and create channel
        console.log("creating");
        bb_admin =      message.guild.channels.create('admin_logs', {parent: bb_cat});
        //End try and create channel
    } else {
        console.log("already exists");
        bb_admin = await message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "admin_logs");
    }
    
    //This always returns a promise
    console.log('bb_admin after',bb_admin);

});

// Login into your bot with the bot token
client.login(config.client.token);
```

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you could provide more context to this snippet of code, preferably a reproducible example. If a fully self contained example is not possible, try to include things like the entire function body and function signature and/or what the code calling the function looks like.

Comment: And yes, you will have to somehow await the returned Promise, you can use the async/await constructs or the Promise `then` method.

Comment: @luawtf Thank you for the reply. I've updated with a very basic example which I hope helps. I'm all for making my code better as it is always learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating an async IIFE as @Viriato suggested, you should turn your current callback to an async function like in my example below.

Also, you should use a variable if you're calling `message.guild.channels.cache.find()` three times :) And you don't need to check if the `find()` method returned `undefined` or checking its  `typeof`. You can simply check if the returned value is truthy.

```js
// make the callback function async
client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith('!')) return;

  let adminLogsChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(
    (channel) => channel.name === 'admin_logs',
  );

  // if admin_logs does not exist, create it
  if (!adminLogsChannel) {
    let parent = message.guild.channels.cache.find(
      (channel) => channel.name === 'BeerBot',
    );
    adminLogsChannel = await message.guild.channels.create('admin_logs', { parent });
  }

  // this returns a GuildChannel now
  console.log('adminLogsChannel after', adminLogsChannel);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, This certainly looks alot cleaner. In this simple example it works (even in my enviroment). But when I try to replicate the changes into my actual file (which is 300 lines of code), I still get the original error of:

"SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules"?

I don't think it's suitable to post my full code here, the only other difference I can see is this "check" happens inside a switch statement of the client.on('message', async (message) => {switch (command) {case 'ping': //trying to insert code here. Could this be the cause?

Comment: You're welcome. You can paste your full code on a site like https://pastebin.com/ and drop the link here in a comment so I can take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you once again for this, It's very helpful. The line starts specifically around 165 and you can find the script: https://pastebin.com/DW6jmD0X (Excuse my bad programming I'm still learning :))

Comment: It's because on line 48 `(e_prefix, row) => {` should be `async (e_prefix, row) => {` ;)